# Apache Solr commands

Tags: solr

ok guys here what i did i secure the admin/ path with a firewall user/password
So untile here everything good.

But i want to keep the searching public but i'm asking you expert,

if someone can do some injection or attack codes with those links query?q and select?q

or its only for searching and nothing affraid to!!

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core/query
http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select
```

Also is there any other commands used in cores except

```
query 
select 
update/
schema
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have to write a client like PHP or python, to allow direct search from Solr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to expose the query interface to the public I would not recommend exposing the Solr URL, I would rather do it via a client application (as Shadif suggested) that proxies Solr and sanitizes the user input parameters.

There are many ways in which a malicious user can submit values to have Solr do things that you probably don't want to. This GitHub repo has a good list possible attacks that you could see: https://github.com/veracode-research/solr-injection

Comment: Thanks @Hector i already have a python script but i would like to run it over php & python and secure myself